# RSS bookmarks in Safari do not update their unread news number

Tags: macos, mac, safari, rss

I've many RSS feeds in my bookmarks collection.

Safari appends the number of new/unread items to the RSS title.
It is really convenient, as I have many RSS feeds I am interested in (and it makes a huge collection), so I only need to check every day which one get updated to click on it. No need to check them one by one. That is what RSS is for, AFAIK (a main feature at least?)

But some of them never get updated. For some of them I need to double click on it to discover it has recent news. Now I've pointed out which rss feeds have that issue (xkcd rss feeds, Linux weekly news, and others), I check them out regularly to get sure I miss nothing (xkcd being the most important one of course)

Did you ever experiment that issue in Safari and how to get rid of it? Could it be the website that does not work properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Benjamin, I've found what it is. Safari preferences only proposes to update RSS feeds located in your Bookmarks bar or in the Bookmarks menu (depending on what options you check in).

Actually some of my bookmarks where located in special directory you can create when clicking on the Bookmark link (the button is located in the left of the bookmark bar right below the previous/next web page button, you know, it represents an open book).

[image]

I've copied all my RSS feeds in the Bookmark menu, and now everyone get updated.

Answer (score 0):

What are your RSS Preferences set to?  Safari --> Preferences --> RSS
Do you have "Automatically update articles in" turned on for Bookmarks bar & Bookmarks menu?
What about check for updates?  Try setting it to 30 minutes....

Turn Remove Articles to "After 2 weeks", if you have it set to every day, then you might be deleting the articles too quickly for you to notice...

Comment: Yet configured as you tell: updated every 30 minutes, and deleted after one month.